# how could I carry over the number for example month 1 = 100 then add that to the answer for month 2? this code is a simple probably not the best

Tags: c, loops

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

float savings, interest; 
int month, months=6;
for (month=1;month<=months;++month){
printf(" Enter the saving ");
scanf("%f" , &savings);

interest= savings + 101.417; 

//(month * savings *1+0.00417* 101.00417 = interest)

printf("%.2f savings = %.2f interest for month %d \n" , savings , interest ,month); 
}
return 0;

}
```

this code is not the best but its trying to work out the interest for a savings account, this is a piece of work written in c.

Comment: I suggest you move the input to before the loop, and then within the loop, add the interest to the savings. Write a little flow chart of what you want to do. Look at the interest calculation too, there should be multiplication by the rate.

Comment: And I suggest you indent your code properly. Readable code is most important.

Comment: Rather than `interest= savings + 101.417`, I would expect something like `interest = my_round(savings * 0.01417, 0.01)`.  Need more details, like why the magic number  101.417?